# Does $\|a\|^2 \le \|a^\ast a\|$ imply $\|a^\ast \| \|a\| \le \|a^2\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a normed algebra with an involution $\ast$. As per title, my question is whether $\|a\| \|a\| \le \|a^\ast a\|$ implies $\|a^\ast \| \|a\| \le \|a^2\|$. I used it in a proof I wrote (without thinking) and when I read my proof again a few days later it occurred to me that this might not be true. Then, the longer I thought about it the more elusive the property became.

Meanwhile, I "fixed" my proof by using a slightly different argument avoiding this (possibly false) implication. Yet I wonder: Is it true of false? By now I suspect that it's actually false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a counter-example:
$$
\|A\|_2^2 = \|A^TA\|_2^2 = \|A^T\|_2\|A\|_2=1,
$$
but
$$
\|A^2\|_2=0
$$